# Unable to connect to mysql through mysql -u root in redhat while connection is successfull from SqlDeveloper

Tags: mysql, linux, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have recently installed **SQLDeveloper** and connected to mysql through it, after which I am facing following error:

```
[root@tborl01 LATER]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
[root@tborl01 LATER]#
```

while connection with same credential is **successful through SQLDeveloper**, this means that the **mysqld is running**.
I have closed the connection through **SQLDeveloper** and again tried to connect through command prompt but faces same error.

I have also tried to start/ restart mysql service:

```
service mysql restart

MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!       [FAILED]
Starting MySQL.................................................................................................../etc/init.d/mysql: line 159: kill: (21944) - No such process
                                                           [FAILED]

Listing running process gives following output( shows mysqld as running)

[root@tborl01 init.d]# ps -eaf | grep mysqld
root      4849     1  0  2011 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/tborl01.pid

mysql     4878  4849  0  2011 ?        02:39:06 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/tborl01.pid --skip-external-locking

root     19572 21368  0 13:42 pts/6    00:00:00 grep mysqld
```

Does **SQLDeveloper** changes some setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. mysql is not the service it is mysqld
2. you need to connect with mysql as

   mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

Try and let me know

Comment: Yes it worked!!  
Thanks a lot!!
But before this error everythime I connect with mysql -u root without specifying hostname, why I had to specify hostname now?